# Cesium intersect mesh and tileset

Tags: javascript, 3d, cesiumjs, geography

Using Cesium with a tileset:

```
var tileset = viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({...}));
```

I'm trying to slice a part from the tileset, for some analysis, can't find a function that does that.

Ideally I'd like to get the **mesh** from the **intersection** of the tileset and **prism**, but getting just the **triangles** around a point or **inside an area** would be great.

(Been searching this for few weeks, if this is RTFM please give me a link)